# Не показывается уведомление notification на android ошибок нет

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Вот код точно из сайта рабочий, что оно хочет, иконка может не такая 100x100px png. Что оно хочет?

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 101
        const val CHANNEL_ID = "channelID"
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            // Создаём уведомление
            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.vk)
                .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
                .setContentText("Пора покормить кота")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
                notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build()) // посылаем уведомление
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет создания канала. `NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel(...));`

Comment: А да я невнимательно руководство официальное прочитал спасибо вам, да там такое есть сейчас глянул.